# mySQL How to select into multiple columns from table based on table conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume we have a table like:

```
| student_id | class_cd   | order_cd |
| ---------- | ---------- | -------- |
| KG112      | TX113      | 1        |
| KG112      | AKI22      | 2        |
| KG112      | KK331      | 2        |
| KG112      | GMT18      | 2        |
| KG112      | ART12      | 2        |
| AO332      | KSD12      | 2        |
| AO332      | MCM15      | 1        |
| AO332      | KK331      | 2        |
| TL531      | CALX1      | 1        |
| TL531      | ALG15      | 2        |
| JP885      | ART12      | 1        |
| JP885      | AKI22      | 2        |
```

As shown from the table above, we assume that each student id can have 1 primary class and 4 secondary classes at once, for a total of 5 classes at once. How can I make a SELECT statement to show a result such that it looks like this:

```
| student_id | pri_class | sec_class1 | sec_class2 | sec_class3 | sec_class4 |
| ---------- | --------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| KG112      | TX113     | AKI22      | KK331      | GMT18      | ART12      |
| AO332      | MCM15     | KSD12      | KK331      |            |            |
| TL531      | CALX1     | ALG15      |            |            |            |
| JP885      | ART12     | AKI22      |            |            |            |
```

As you can see, each row pertains to that students classes where if they do not have up to 5 classes, then to leave the remainder blank. The order does not matter as to which classes show after the primary, only the primary, indicated by `1` has to be under `pri_class` and the secondary, indicated by `2` can be randomly placed after the primary.

My attempt: literally been at this for 2 hours and have made 0 progress.

Comment: Note your data set as presented has no way to determine ordering for your four secondary columns

Comment: Take a look it might help if your `MySQL` supports window functions https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=180a8c01830e55f23920a712ae794033

Comment: @Stu i said if its indicated by ```2``` then it can be placed randomly